# Issue with Random Image module in Joomla 3.9.13?

Tags: module, joomla

I created the folder and uploaded 3 jpg images. And putting the right path in Image Folder. But it still not show the images on page.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can get Joomla help on the dedicated SE site [joomla.se].   This isn't really a programming question (it's a using Joomla question).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct to me.

I suggest trying an alternative path for the Image Folder such as:

```
/images/Manifestation_Miracle
```

I also suggest renaming the folder to remove the underscore to see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Neil. I discovered there was an extra space right after the path I put in the Image Folder.

And my problem was solved after I removed that gap. Thank you for your support!